# How to disable B frames in FFmpeg for H.264 encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, nvenc

I'm encoding video with h264_nvenc, and I would like to disable B-Frames. I'm trying to use `-bframes 0` parameter, but I'm not sure if it works, and where exactly put the command.
For now, this is my code:

```
-probesize 10MB -s 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -i video.h264 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset p7 -tune 4 -rc:v vbr -cq:v 1 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -r:v 30 video.h264
```

Furthermore, should I need to use `bframes 0` when I'm already using `tune 4` (lossless)?

The original video doesn't have any B-frame.

Comment: Just to add that using profile **Baseline** (instead of current profile **High**) will create a non B-frame video. Just test if the output is suitable with your picture resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFmpeg option is:

> **bf integer (encoding,video)**
> Set max number of B frames between non-B-frames.
>
> Must be an integer between -1 and 16. 0 means that B-frames are disabled. If a > value of -1 is used, it will choose an automatic value depending on the encoder.
>
> Default value is 0.

In `libavcodec/nvenc.c` it sets `frameIntervalP` (`0` - intra-only, `1` - IPP, `2` - IBP, `3` - IBBP etc.):

```
if (avctx->gop_size > 0) {
    if (avctx->max_b_frames >= 0) {
        /* 0 is intra-only, 1 is I/P only, 2 is one B-Frame, 3 two B-frames, and so on. */
        ctx->encode_config.frameIntervalP = avctx->max_b_frames + 1;
    }

    ctx->encode_config.gopLength = avctx->gop_size;
} else if (avctx->gop_size == 0) {
    ctx->encode_config.frameIntervalP = 0;
    ctx->encode_config.gopLength = 1;
}
```

For the older `LosslessHP` preset the `frameIntervalP` is `1` (IPP).

If you use the new presets as recommended you should set it manually.
See the [NVENC Preset Migration Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/nvenc-preset-migration-guide/).